# Diferencias y limitaciones entre int[] e Integer[]

Tags: java, array

Teniendo en cuenta que tanto `int[]` e `Integer[]` son [objetos según la documentación de Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An object is a class instance or an array.

Y que `Integer` es la [clase (tipo de referencia) que encapsula de manera inmutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) in valor `int` (tipo primitivo), me gustaría saber las diferencias de su uso, sus limitaciones y que ventajas y desventajas implica.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55738/discussion-on-question-by-awes0mem4n-diferencias-y-limitaciones-entre-int-e-in).

Answer (score -14):

La diferencia entre ambos arreglos esta directa y únicamente relacionada con los [tipos que contienen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) como se dice en la pregunta y se puede encontrar fácilmente en Internet. No obstante esto implica y limita algunas operaciones específicas sobre cada uno de los arreglos:

#### Diferencias con el tipo `null`

El arreglo `int[]` no puede contener nunca valores `null` pues según la [documentación de Java al respecto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1):

> The null reference can always be assigned or cast to any reference type

Esto queda demostrado por la siguiente línea de código y su resultado:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new int[2]));
```

> out: [0, 0]

De la misma forma nunca devolverá `null`, ni aunque intentes asignarle un valor `(Integer)null`. Esto último compilará pero te dará una NPE.

`Integer[]` si permite asignar valores nulos.

#### Díferencias en el heap

Respecto a la localización, si bien los arreglos como objetos que son van a residir en el **heap** en los dos casos, hay una diferencia.

- `int[]` los tipos primitivos `int` van a estar incrustados con el arreglo.
- `Integer[]` los tipos de referencia `Integer` van a estar cada uno en el **heap** como objetos que son y el arreglo va a tener incrustados la referencia a cada uno de estos objetos de la clase `Integer`. Los `int que encapsula cada`Integer` estarán incrustados dentro de su correspondiente objeto que los encapsula, no en el arreglo.

Respecto a la ocupación de memoria, `Integer` ocupa aproximadamente el doble que el `int` correspondiente.

#### Diferencias en la velocidad de cálculo

Los cálculos sobre tipos primitivos son más rápidos. No obstante `Integer` incluye optimizaciones para que no haya diferencias apreciables, pero si se trata de código crítico es mejor usar `int`.

#### Conclusión

Por lo visto anteriormente, en general es mejor usar `int[]` siempre que se pueda y dejar el uso de `Integer[]` para cuando sea necesario: cuando haga falta usar valores `null` o sin inicializar en el arreglo, o cuando se requiera de un objeto tipo `Integer[]` o `Integer` en el código como si necesitaras posteriormente añadirlo a una colección.

**EDITO** (gracias a LuiggiMendoza):

Una diferencia clara de usar `int[]` e `Integer[]` es cuando envías objetos de estos tipos a un método que usa varargs como `void ejemplo(Object ... args)`. Si lo llamas `ejemplo (new int[] { 1, 2, 3})` Java lo reconoce como 1 argumento. Si lo llamas `ejemplo(1, 2, 3)` Java hace un boxing de `int` a `Integer` y lo reconoce como 3 argumentos. Si lo llamas como `ejemplo(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3})` Java lo reconoce como 3 argumentos de tipo `Integer`.

Comment: Adicional: `int[]` no se puede convertir a una colección de `Integer` tan fácilmente p.e. `List<Integer>`. Se necesita hacer la conversión de cada elemento de `int` a `Integer` como paso previo. Esto incluye a Java 8 y streams. Ojo que los streams trabajan con los wrappers como es el caso de `Integer` a menos que uses el stream particular para primitivo, que en este caso es [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

Comment: Yo no he hablado nada de `List` y tampoco el OP de la anterior. Por eso digo que se use `int` excepto si hay que usar `Integer`. Si hay que añadirlo a una lista o un mapa sería el caso. Y a las malas un lo cargas con un `for`. No se si te he entendido bien.

Comment: Sí, pero se suele trabajar más con las colecciones que con los arreglos, a menos que estés leyendo o consumiendo información de alguna librería particular. Por ende la acotación de qué es mejor para usar. Y es una diferencia importante. Un ejemplo clásico es al usar `Arrays#asList(int[])` que devuelve `List<int[]>` con un solo elemento, el arreglo, mientras que si usas `Arrays#asList(Integer[])` devuelve `List<Integer>` con múltiples elementos, uno por cada elemento del arreglo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en lo que dices, pero no era objeto de la pregunta. No obstante la detallo más para que quede claro.

Comment: En realidad es parte de las diferencias entre `int[]` e `Integer[]`, creo que sí debería ser parte de la respuesta.